# Dropdown eventlistener does not display anythinig on the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an event listener. After selecting the option, the page should display the option with the value from the array, but for some reason does not work.

I don't want to use `onchange` in the HTML because that is the only way I manage to do but I am not happy with it.

Could anyone give me advise how can I display on the page after the user selects an option?

```js
function currencyRates(currency) {
  let currency_Rates = [{
    "UK Pounds": 0.73,
    "Euros": 0.85,
    "Yen": 110.54,
    "Yuan": 6.48,
    "Swiss Franc": 0.92,
    "Canadian Dollars": 1.26
  }];

  let currencyType = document.getElementById("currencies");
  for (let i = 0; i < currency_Rates.length; i++) {
    let currencyCountry = document.createElement("option");
    let currency_Country = document.createTextNode(currency_Rates[i].value);
    currencyCountry.appendChild(currency_Country);

  }

  document.getElementById('exchangerate').innerHTML = "One US Dollar buys you " + CURRENCY_RATE[currencyType] + " " + currencyType;
}
window.onload = () => {
  let theSelect = document.getElementById("exchangerate");
  theSelect.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let text = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    currencyRates(currencies);
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<select id="currencies" ;>
  <option>Select a Currency</option>
  <option>UK Pounds</option>
  <option>Euros</option>
  <option>Yen</option>
  <option>Yuan</option>
  <option>Swiss Francs</option>
  <option>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Comment: line 19:  `CURRENCY_RATE[currencyType]` CURRENCY_RATE is not defined

Comment: `let theSelect = document.getElementById("exchangerate");` is selecting a paragraph that never changes, not the dropdown `<select>` element. `CURRENCY_RATE` is not defined, and I'm not sure what `document.createElement("option")` is supposed to achieve. Can you clarify?

Comment: You are not appending the `currencyCountry`, which is a created element, to the DOM anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simplify things by just referencing your currency rates object right from the change handler. The select menu will be the event target.

```js
let currency_Rates = {
  "UK Pounds": 0.73,
  "Euros": 0.85,
  "Yen": 110.54,
  "Yuan": 6.48,
  "Swiss Francs": 0.92,
  "Canadian Dollars": 1.26
};

window.onload = () => {
  let theSelect = document.getElementById("currencies");
  theSelect.addEventListener("change", e => {
    let rate = currency_Rates[e.target.value]
    document.querySelector('#exchangerate').innerHTML = `One US Dollar buys you ${rate} worth of ${e.target.value}`;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<select id="currencies">
  <option>Select a Currency</option>
  <option>UK Pounds</option>
  <option>Euros</option>
  <option>Yen</option>
  <option>Yuan</option>
  <option>Swiss Francs</option>
  <option>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

A more concise method would be to encode the rates right into the dropdown, then you can access them directly and not worry about matching names.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let theSelect = document.getElementById("currencies");
  theSelect.addEventListener("change", e => {
    let rate = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset.rate
    document.querySelector('#exchangerate').innerHTML = `One US Dollar buys you ${rate} worth of ${e.target.value}`;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<select id="currencies">
  <option>Select a Currency</option>
  <option data-rate='0.73'>UK Pounds</option>
  <option data-rate='0.85'>Euros</option>
  <option data-rate='110.54'>Yen</option>
  <option data-rate='6.48'>Yuan</option>
  <option data-rate='0.92'>Swiss Francs</option>
  <option data-rate='1.26'>Canadian Dollars</option>
</select>
<p id="exchangerate"></p>
```

Comment: you're welcome. I added an alternate method just now